# UIScrollView's zoomToRect needs to be called twice

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I want to pan to a certain point in my `UIScrollView` and while doing so also zoom into the maximum zoom level. Leaving out the zoom rect calculation here, it seems that `zoomToRect` needs to be called twice to zoom and pan where I want it to.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(zoom) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
[self performSelector:@selector(zoom) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
[self performSelector:@selector(zoom) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

- (void) zoom
{
    [self.imageScrollView zoomToRect:(CGRect){ 913.556, 0, 320, 465 }
                            animated:YES];
}
```

The first `zoom` call zooms in, but it takes the second call to actually pan to the correct position. Once at the proper position the 3rd call does nothing - which is what I already expected for the 2nd call.

What's the problem here? According to [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) I would expect it to just work on the first call.

A sample project is available on [github](https://github.com/tcurdt/ZoomTest).

Comment: That's strange. Could you post an isolated sample code project on github? Does the same thing happen if you call zoom directly without performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

Comment: Yeah, the performSelector I just used to make it easily reproducible. It's normally directly called from a CoreLocation delegate method. Will try to create a project for it.

Comment: Alright - was able to create a simple project to reproduce this. Now available on github at https://github.com/tcurdt/ZoomTest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is the overridden layoutSubviews which centers the image view. This effects the position of the resulting frame after the first call of

```
[self.scrollView zoomToRect:(CGRect){ 913.556, 0, 320, 465 } animated:YES];
```

I did some tests and found a **quick hack**, maybe this guides you to a solution which fits your needs:

1.) Override zoomToRect: to indicate that you doing a **automatic zooming**:

```
- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.automaticZooming = YES;
    [super zoomToRect:rect animated:animated];
}
```

2.) Make the adjustment of the image view in layoutSubviews **depend on** the automaticZooming state:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
...
    if (!self.automaticZooming) {
        imageView.frame = frameToCenter;
    }
...
}
```

3.) **Reset** automaticZooming state after a zooming is done:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    self.automaticZooming = NO;
}
```

Comment: Hah! You pointed me into the right direction. It seems like just removing the `frameToCenter.origin.(x|y) = 0` does the trick. Not even sure why that is in there yet.

Comment: @tcurdt Thank you for answering your own question here! I'd downloaded your sample project and have been tweaking it to try to understand UIScrollView zoom behavior, and modifying those lines in the `PSTLayoutSubviewCenteredScrollView` (and calling `layoutSubviews` from `scrollViewDidZoom`) causes that class's zoom to behave nicely.

Comment: Wow - such an old question/answer. Glad it was still useful.